# Which spring transaction isolation level to use to maintain a counter for product sold?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data

I have an e-commerce site written with Spring Boot + Angular. I need to maintain a counter in my product table for tracking how many has been sold. But the counter sometime becomes inaccurate when many users are ordering the same item concurrently.

In my service code, I have the following transactional declaration:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)`

in which, after persisting the order (using `CrudRepository.save()`), I do a select query to sum the quantities being ordered so far, hoping the select query will count all orders have been committed. But that doesn't seem to be the case, from time to time, the counter is less than the actual number.

Same issue happens for my other use case: quantity limit a product. I use the same transaction isolation setting. In the code, I'll do a select query to see how many has been sold and throw out of stock error if we can't fulfill the order. But for hot items, we some times oversold the item because each thread doesn't see the orders just committed in other threads.

So is `READ_COMMITTED` the right isolation level for my use case? Or I should do pessimistic locking for this use case?

**UPDATE 05/13/17**

I chose Ruben's approach as I know more about java than database so I took the easier road for me. Here's what I did.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void updateOrderCounters(Purchase purchase, ACTION action)
```

I'm use JpaRepository so I don't play entityManager directly. Instead, I just put the code to update counters in a separate method and annotated as above. It seems to work well so far. I have seen >60 concurrent connections making orders and no oversold and the response time seems ok as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you retrieve the total sold items count the available options might differ :

**1. If you calculate the sold items count dynamically via a `sum` query on orders**

I believe in this case the option you have is using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for the transaction, since this is the only one which supports `range locks` and prevents `phantom reads`. 
However, I would not really recommend going with this isolation level since it has a major performance impact on your system (or used really carefully on a well designed spots only).

Links : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_serializable

**2. If you maintain a counter on product or some other row associated with the product**

In this case I would probably recommend using `row level locking` eg `select for update` in a service method which checks the availability of the product and increments the sold items count. The high level algorithm of the product placement could be similar to the steps below :

1. Retrieve the row storing the number of remaining/sold items count using the `select for update` query (`@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` on a repository method).
2. Make sure that the retrieved row has up to date field values since it could be retrieved from the Hibernate session level cache (hibernate would just execute `select for update` query on the `id` just to acquire the lock). You can achieve this by calling 'entityManager.refresh(entity)'.
3. Check the `count` field of the row and if the value is fine with your business rules then increment/decrement it.
4. Save the entity, flush the hibernate session, and commit the transaction (explicitly or implicitly).

A meta code is below :

```
    @Transactional
    public Product performPlacement(@Nonnull final Long id) {
        Assert.notNull(id, "Product id should not be null");
        entityManager.flush();
        final Product product = entityManager.find(Product.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
        // Make sure to get latest version from database after acquiring lock, 
        // since if a load was performed in the same hibernate session then hibernate will only acquire the lock but use fields from the cache
        entityManager.refresh(product);
        // Execute check and booking operations
        // This method call could just check if availableCount > 0
        if(product.isAvailableForPurchase()) {
            // This methods could potentially just decrement the available count, eg, --availableCount
            product.registerPurchase();
        }
        // Persist the updated product 
        entityManager.persist(product);
        entityManager.flush();
        return product;
    }
```

This approach will make sure that **no any two threads/transactions will be ever performing a check and update on the same row storing the count of a product concurrently**.

However, because of that it will also have some performance degradation effect on your system hence it is essential to make sure that atomic increment/decrement is being used **as far** in the purchase flow as possible and **as rare** as possible (eg, right in the checkout handling routine when customer hits `pay`). Another useful trick for minimizing the effect of a lock would be adding that 'count' column not on a product itself but on a different table which is associated with the product. This will prevent you from locking the products rows, since the locks will be acquired on a different row/table combination which are used purely during the checkout stage.

Links: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

**Summary**

Please note that both of the techniques introduce extra synchronization points in your system hence reducing throughput. So please make sure to carefully measure the impact it has on your system via performance test or any other technique which is being used in your project for measuring the throughput.

Quite often online shops choose going towards overselling/booking some items rather then affecting the performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I was doing the first approach, will give the second approach a try.

Comment: Seems to work. Two days now and I haven't seen anything oversold yet. :)

Answer (score 3):

With these transaction settings, you should see the stuff that is committed. But still, your transaction handling isn't water tight. The following might happen:

- Let's say you have one item in stock left.
- Now two transactions start, each ordering one item.
- Both check the inventory and see: "Fine enough stock for me."
- Both commit.
- Now you oversold.

[Isolation level serializable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#SERIALIZABLE) should fix that. *BUT*

1. the isolation levels available in different databases vary widely, so I don't think it is actually guaranteed to give you the requested isolation level
2. this limits seriously limits scalability. The transactions doing this should be as short and as rare as possible.

Depending on the database you are using it might be a better idea to implement this with a database constraint. In oracle, for example, you could create a materialized view calculating the complete stock and put a constraint on the result to be non-negative.

**Update**

For the materialized view approach you do the following.

1. create materialized view, that calculates the value that you want to constraint, e.g. the sum of orders. Make sure the materialized view gets updated in the transaction that change the content of the underlyingt tables.

   For oracle this is achieved by the `ON COMMIT` clause.

   > ON COMMIT Clause
   >
   > Specify ON COMMIT to indicate that a fast refresh is to occur whenever the database commits a transaction that operates on a master table of the materialized view. This clause may increase the time taken to complete the commit, because the database performs the refresh operation as part of the commit process.

   See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm for more details.
2. Put a check constraint on that materialized view to encode the constraint that you want, e.g. that the value is never negative. Note, that a materialized view is just another table, so you can create constraints just as you would normaly do.

   See fore example https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We're using MySQL database. Is there a reason for using materialized view (My DB knowledge is limited). Can I add a column to my product table for quantity_remain and set non-negative constraint on it? Actually I guess this doesn't solve the problem since both thread still would think there're enough stock left and would update the quantity left accordingly. I need to write code in my db (trigger or something) to update quantity_remain?

Comment: The other approach I've tried is to start a new transaction within the parent transaction above just to do a select query for the count. But that didn't seem to work either (I didn't use the SERIALIZE isolation level though). Is this a sensible approach?

Comment: I don't think the inner transaction would change anything. What you essentially need is a constraint that affects multiple rows at once. This isn't possible with normal constraints, hence the approach of using materialized views. Of course, an alternative is to not mind the overselling and handling it afterward, basically doing "eventual consistency"

Comment: I see. Would it be possible for you to describe the steps needs to use materialized view to solve the prevent-oversold use case?

Comment: If my update to the answer is sufficient. Otherwise, I propose you create a new question for that.

Comment: So in my java code, I don't really read from this materialized view? I still just operate on the `product` and `order` table? And if the `on commit` update to the materialized view causes constraint error, the java code that commits the order will receive an db constraint error and rollback. Is that how it will work?

Comment: You may read from it, which would require an additional entity. Completely up to you. Otherwise: yes, that's how it works.

Comment: I marked Ruben's answer as correct because that's the approach I took and I am more comfortable with Java changes than DB changes. Thanks for your answer. I would have marked your answer as correct too if I could. :-)

Comment: No worry. But you should upvote his answer as well, since I guess it was helpful.